# GoRouter swipe back gesture is not detected

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, gorouter

Hi i am using GoRouter to build my app's navigation but it doesn't detect the swipe back gestures of android and ios, it goes back and renders the correct page but i don't see the state.subloc changes inside my redirect function of my GoRouter. Is this expected behavior? I mean , is it not supported by go_router yet?

Comment: Could you please add the code where you are facing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug got solved by go_router team by a [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117622).

Comment: i have an issue when i swipe outside the app to main phone screen,
i get exception when i try to reopen the app 
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugcurrentbuildtarget == this': is not true. framework.dart:4692 the relevant error-causing widget was uncontrolledproviderscope